# How does UV mapping work for the spaces between vertices?

Tags: 3d, rendering, uv-mapping

In UV mapping each vertex has a UV coordinate, but wouldn't that just make 1 pixel for every vertex? How do you find out the texture coordinate for the spaces in between the vertices? Am I not understanding UV mapping right?

Comment: No, it wouldn't. To find out the space between the vertices you use interpolation.

Comment: @tkausl So it kind of cuts the shape of the triangle out of the UV map?

Comment: Yes, basically, that's it.

Comment: It "kind of" cuts out a triangle between the three UV-coordinates which has not necessarily the same size as the triangle in the "world".

Comment: Each vertex has only one XYZ coordinate, so doesn't that just make 1 pixel for every vertex?

Comment: Yes, but we are talking about triangles here, all the pixels inbetween corner vertices get on to that triangle. If you to UV map a single vertex .. then yes, it will get the single color.

Comment: As far as I remember, UV coordinates are the set of 2 coordinates X and Y, means XY only, not XYZ. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Actually every face of your mesh has UV coordinates through which UV mapping works. Let take an example of cube.

Cube has 6 faces and every face has 4 coordinates. That means a Cube must have 24 coordinates for UV mapping.

Now second part is to map coordinates with texture. Let's take an example of a square texture image having 6 different color boxes ( for each face actually). This means texture has 2 rows and 3 columns of color boxes containing 6 different colours. Have a look

[image: Sample]

Now if I want to map red color on Cube's top face let say and I know that the coordinates at 0, 1, 2, 3 represents the top face of cube. Then I would map as

- Coordinate at **0** would map **0,1** of texture
- Coordinate at **1** would map **0.33,1** of texture
- Coordinate at **2** would map **0.33,0.5** of texture
- Coordinate at **3** would map **0,0.5** of texture

As texture's points lies between 0 and 1. And if **0.33** is not clear then it is **1/3** of total width because **1/3 + 1/3 + 1/3 = 1**

Comment: You are welcome, If you are now clear from my answer then you should consider to mark it as answer. Its a good practice :)